# Output of hyperbfit?

Tags: estimation, parameterization

I want to fit a hyperbolid distribution to my data, in my notation, I have the density
\begin{align*}
H(l;\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta)&=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)
\end{align*}

with R using HyperbolicDist package and the hyperbFit command I get the output
parameter estimates:

```
pi    zeta    delta     mu
0.09    0.2   0.002   -0.002
```

can someone explain me, what this parameterization is in my case? So I do not have a pi and zeta?

Answer (score -1):

See [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GeneralizedHyperbolic/GeneralizedHyperbolic.pdf) page 40 the command hyperbChangePars. You can change to your desired parameterization. The used density is on page 55.

so in your case

```
hyperbChangePars(from=1,to=2,c( -0.002,0.002,0.09, 0.2))
```